# Do I need Oracle Java to develop/run Xamarin Apps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Does the Xamarin development environment need anything from Oracle's Java, either JRE or SDKs? It seems that whatever it needs in terms of Java, it gets it from the Android SDKs which are already part of the Xamarin downloads.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to remove the Oracle Java VM from my machine, since I don't run any Java apps.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need Java JDK v1.6. This should be installed by the Xamarin Installer automatically.

And as you mentioned, you'll update the Android SDKs and tools using the Android SDK Manager. I would check regularly for updates to these SDKs because Xamarin doesn't install them.